# Extracting column only from R spatial dataframe without $ notation

Tags: r

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R, from which I would like to extract a vector of one of the columns. This can be done easily by using the `$` notation, e.g. `dataFrame$columnName`. My code however needs to pass the column names as strings, in which case I would normally use the bracket notation `dataFrame[,'columnName']` to get the same result. R-spatial however, [per the documentation](http://rspatial.org/spatial/rst/7-vectmanip.html#variables), doesn't seem to allow this, returning instead a full SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object with geometry added to the single requested column.

How can I go from a string of the column name to just a vector of the data in that column? I'd prefer to do this without creating a separate non-spatial dataframe if possible.

Comment: Call the slot explicitly ie., x@data[,"colname"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subset the `@data` slot which is a plain data frame, but its not always a good idea to access members of an object class via slots, in which case you can convert to a plain data frame with `as.data.frame`, which drops the geometry and gives back a plain data frame:

```
bar_vector = as.data.frame(spfoo)[,"bar"]
```

One advantage of using `as.data.frame` instead of the slot is that this will also work if your spatial object is one of the new `sf` classes.

Comment: Nice that this will work with sp and sf objects.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `$`-operator as a function

```
`$`(dataFrame, 'columnName')
```

Or you could make use of the function `extract2()` from the `magrittr` package, that is basically the same as `$` or `[[`:

```
magrittr::extract2(dataFrame, 'columnName')
```

The motivation behind `extract2()` is actually that it can be used in pipes. So you could also do

```
library(magrittr)
dataFrame %>% extract2('columnName')
```

All these solutions also work with `sf` objects.